# why teradata always show time one hour less than what shown in timestamp?

Tags: teradata

I' m running the following query when I cast a string to timestamp and then try to only get the time, it will show the time-1hour. However when I try extract the hours only it is working properly.

I've tried the following query to understand why this is happening.

```
SELECT Cast ('2019-10-13 16:00:01' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS a,
   Cast('08:00:00' AS TIME(0))                  AS JiraStart,
   Cast(a AS TIME(0))                           AS A_time,
   Extract(hour FROM jirastart)                 AS JE_hour,
   Extract(hour FROM a)                         AS A_hour;
```

I expect the A_time to be '16:00:01' but this what I get:'15:00:01'

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrqVk.png)

Comment: Proably Timezones?

Comment: I do't think Timezone is the problem because both time and timestamp follow the same timezone. This message is from the system : 'Default Time format HH:MI:SS.S(F)Z
Default Timestamp format YY/MM/DDBHH:MI:SS.S(F)Z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session is set to a daylight saving timezone and when you cast to a time without time zone it assumes the current displacement and adjusts it to the standard time.

You can either cast to time/timestamps with time zone:

```
SET TIME Zone 'europe central';

SELECT Cast ('2017-10-13 16:00:01' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS a,
   Cast(a AS TIME(0))                           AS A_time,
   a AT LOCAL                                   AS A_local,
   Cast(a AS TIME(0)) AT LOCAL                  AS A_time_local,
   Cast ('2019-10-13 16:00:01' AS TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME Zone) AS a_TZ,
   Cast(a_TZ AS TIME(0) WITH TIME Zone) AS time_TZ;

                  a    A_time                    A_local    A_time_local                       a_TZ         time_TZ
-------------------  --------  -------------------------  --------------  -------------------------  --------------
2017-10-13 16:00:01  15:00:01  2017-10-13 16:00:01+02:00  15:00:01+01:00  2019-10-13 16:00:01+02:00  16:00:01+02:00
```

Or switch the session to a fixed time zone:

```
SET TIME Zone 0;

SELECT Cast ('2017-10-13 16:00:01' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS a,
   Cast(a AS TIME(0))                           AS A_time,
   a AT LOCAL                                   AS A_TZ,
   Cast(a AS TIME(0)) AT LOCAL                  AS A_timeTZ;

                  a    A_time                       A_TZ        A_timeTZ
-------------------  --------  -------------------------  --------------
2017-10-13 16:00:01  16:00:01  2017-10-13 16:00:01+00:00  16:00:01+00:00
```